# ActiveModel: proper relation for a different type of the resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm trying to determine the proper ActiveModel realtionship for the following situation: there are pictures and there are different categories of them: foo, bar, baz and qux. A User can set one like and several comments per the picture. 
I started with a `Catregory` and a `Foo` models. The simpliest approach could be - creatation of `likes` and `comments` properties for each of the Foo, Bar, Baz and Qux models. But I feel it's a silly approach... There might be a better one.
What is the best kind of realationship can be chosen for such a case?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a little more? If it is what I understood, maybe polymorphic associations can help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: There are several kinds of models (pictures in my case), each of them can have several likes and comments. I should prevent DRY somehow and also make each model having it's own likes and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I imagined reading your question (I've decided that your pictures were created by users, because your model looks a lot like a social network):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
  has_many :comments
  has_one :like
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :likes
  has_many :comments
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :picture
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :picture
end
```

Categories are rows of the `categories` Table. Instead of making one Model per category, you should have one model `Category` for all of them, with attributes like `name`, `color` or whatever you want.

Comment: Why do you declare `likes` as standalone model?

Comment: Because you'll need to query a message's likes, or a person's likes. Don't you ?

Comment: Actually what I need are Foos, Bars, Bazes and Quxes with likes and comments.

Comment: Just create them in the Category model : `foo = Category.create(name: "Foo")` creates a row in the categories table. Then you can create a Picture for this Category : `pic = Picture.create(image: mon_image, category: foo)` and a like for this Picture : `Like.create(picture: pic, user: current_user)`

Comment: You categories are datas in your database. They are instances of a Category model.

If you absolutely need to have different behaviours for each category, you can have a different model for each category AND still have them as instances of the same Category Model with the "Single Table Inheritance" principle : http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/